# Показать окно для ввода параметра

Tags: bash, linux

Как вывести окно, чтобы туда можно было ввести параметр?

Comment: @maza51, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Установите пакет dialog:

> This application provides a method of displaying several different types
>  of dialog boxes from shell scripts.  This allows a developer of a script
>  to interact with the user in a much friendlier manner.

```
apt-get install dialog
```

Возможно потребуется установить еще и ncurses

После чего можно делать так:

```
#!/bin/bash
: ${DIALOG=dialog}
: ${DIALOG_OK=0}
: ${DIALOG_CANCEL=1}
: ${DIALOG_ESC=255}
tempfile=`tempfile 2>/dev/null` || tempfile=/tmp/test$$
trap "rm -f $tempfile" 0 1 2 5 15
$DIALOG --title "INPUT BOX" --clear "$@"  --inputbox "Введите что-нть" 8 16 2> $tempfile

retval=$?

case $retval in
  $DIALOG_OK)
    echo "Result: `cat $tempfile`";;
  $DIALOG_CANCEL)
    echo "Cancel pressed.";;
  $DIALOG_ESC)
    if test -s $tempfile ; then
      cat $tempfile
    else
      echo "ESC pressed."
    fi
  ;;
esac
```

Больше примеров можно найти в /usr/share/doc/dialog/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам подойдет read. Эта команда не выводит дополнительное окно, а просто ждет ввода в терминале и заносит введенную строку в указанную после read переменную.